# What is the intersection of all Sobolev spaces of square integrable functions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If

$$H^k=\{f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: D^\alpha f \in L^2(U)\ \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n \ \text{with} \ \vert \alpha \vert \leq k \}$$

then how do I show that

$$\cap _{k \geq 2} H^k \subset C^\infty (U)$$

Is there a dircet approach that does not go through Morrey's and the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality?

Comment: Is the set $U$ a bounded Lipschitz open set or can it be anything in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

Comment: Does it work for any open set? I actually only need open balls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to define the Hilbert-Sobolev spaces $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $s \in \mathbb{R}$, and this is a corollary to the continuous inclusion theorem Sobolev, which you can view here:

[If $u \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $s > n/2$, then $u \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666477/if-u-in-hs-mathbbrn-for-s-n-2-then-u-in-l-infty-mathbbrn/1667350#1667350)

and $\bigcap_{s \in \mathbb{R}} H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
In particular, if $s=m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)=H^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with equivalent norms,
and it can be shown that, if $m-k > n/2$, then $H^m(\Omega) \hookrightarrow C^k(\Omega)$, and also $\bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} H^m(\Omega) \subset C^k(\Omega)$, with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open.

Comment: Sincerely other roads does not know them. But the regularity of PDE believe that studying these spaces is almost essential

Comment: Where can I see the proof of your last assertion, please?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Y. Egorov e B.W. Schulze, Pseudo-differential Operators, Singularities, Applications. Birkhauser, 1996.